# e-mail sent out from <user>@<hostname> instead of <user>@<domain>

Tags: email

When I send an e-mail from my server(hostname of the server is *syslog*) with command `(echo "To: blah@example.com"; echo "From: root@example.org"; echo "Subject: test; echo; echo "test"; echo) | sendmail -t`, then MTA of *example.com* complains that domain of sender address *root@syslog* does not exist. Why doesn't my MTA use the address *root@example.org* instead of *root@syslog*? I have specified *example.org* as a domain in my */etc/resolv.conf* file:

```
root@syslog:~# grep domain /etc/resolv.conf 
domain example.org
root@syslog:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the `From:` header and the envelope sender. Try to use `| sendmail -t -f 'root@example.org'` to use a different sender address